# How to center horizontally a view that is part of a view group in SwiftUI

Tags: layout, swiftui

I am trying to layout two groups of labels ("<<","<","^",">",">>","[]") and ("M") horizontally at the bottom of the screen using SwiftUI with the constraint that the ("M") group is in the bottom right corner of the screen, and the ("<<","<","^",">",">>","[]") group is centered in such a way that the "^" element aligns with the horizontal center of the screen.

I tried this:

```
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
                HStack.init(spacing: 4) {
                    Text("<<")
                    Text("<")
                    Text("^") // this view should be aligned to horizontal center of screen
                        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                    Text(">")
                    Text(">>")
                    Text("[]")
                        .padding(.leading, 8)
                }
                Spacer()
                Text("M")
                    .padding(2)
            }
        }
```

which looks like this:

[image]

I don't know how to constrain the "^" to align with the horizontal center.

Using autolayout I could do this quite easily by anchoring the "^"'s center-x to the parent center-x anchor, and then anchoring the remaining elements to "^" accordingly, where the "M" would be anchored to the bottom-right anchor.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use the same length Text on both sides with .hidden() modifier.

(I'm using Group here, because I'm over 10 limit View)

```
VStack {
    Spacer()
    HStack {
        Group {
            Text("M").hidden()
            Spacer()
            Text("[]").hidden()
            Text("<<")
            Text("<")
        }
        Group {
            Text("^")
            Text(">")
            Text(">>")
            Text("[]")
            Spacer()
            Text("M")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is hacky and possibly not transferrable to similar problems.  An alternate solution is to use a ZStack and position the views manually, but that's also not what I'm looking for.  A SwiftUI alignment/anchoring/modifier solution is what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you haven't seen: https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/ then it's a very clear guide to alignment.  Don't know if it will help with your problem.